# Google autocomplete, multiple pages

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've come across a little problem with autocomplete. I use a base.jsp page which has the following in a init function:

```
var input = document.getElementById('addressField');         
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
    types: ["geocode"]
});   

autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
```

I got two pages, one.jsp and two.jsp.

ons.jsp contains the following input type, which is tied to the autocomplete. This one works.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="address"  aria-label="..." id="addressField" value="">
```

two.jsp as the exacty same. But this one does not work?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" aria-label="..." id="addressField"  value="">
```

I do not understand how two identical input fields can have one working and one not. Both share the same base, and the autocomplete initialization.

What can possible cause this? I've got no idea where to look-

Answer (score 1):

Here's where I'd start:

```
var input = document.getElementById('addressField');         
console.log(input);
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
    types: ["geocode"]
});   
console.log(autocomplete);
console.log(map);
autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);   
console.log('--------------- Done -----------');
console.log(input);
```

Then look at the output of the browser log and see what's different.  Computers only do what we tell them :-)